# Custom permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress

суть проблемы такова , есть страница www.site/kursi и так же есть родители с дочерними страницами пример www.site/predops/roditel/dochernaya, использую custom permainks чтобы привести к виду www.site/kursi/%postname%/ , но пермалинки не приводятся к этому виду.

```
function my_custom_post_kursi() {
$labels = array(
   'labels'        => $labels,
   'description'   => 'Пользовательский тип записей Учителя и уроки',
   'public'        => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'https://i.imgur.com/eo8G2b3.png',
   'menu_position' => 1,
   'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail', 'kursi-category','post-formats'),
   'has_archive'   => true,
);
register_post_type( 'kursi', $args );
```

}

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_kursi' );
```

Не сильно силен в php , буду благодарен за помощь и разъяснения

Comment: после добавления кода регистрации кастомного типа поста вы не забыли пересохранить настройки постоянных ссылок? Без этого ссылки могут не заработать, даже если вы всё сделали правильно

Comment: Да сохранял в админке в custom permalink , безуспешно

Comment: у вас в коде что-то странное. Вы создаёте параметры в массиве `$labels`, а в  `register_post_type` передаёте `$args`. Ну и заодно не помешает задать свойство `rewrite` явно

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: @alenkins безуспешно, главное отображение в custom permalinsk есть www.site/kursi/%postname%/
has_archive: true / with_front: true
Но сами линки не приходят к такому виду

Comment: скопировал ваш код, поставил плагин, у меня все работает. Вы точно пересахранили пермалинки?  Нужно зайти в раздел `настройки->постоянные ссылки`(просто зайти).

Comment: @Алексей Да добавил массив в function.php, зашел в админку постоянные ссылки -> сохранить изминения, может проблема в плагине? подскажите какой вы ставили?

Comment: Какой указали.Что конкретно не отображается посты или страница выдает 404? Плагин не нужен если вы хотите чтобы ссылки были вида  www.site/kursi/%postname%/.Отключите его, поставьте тип ссылок как `Название записи`.

Comment: @Алексей выдает 404